# ActionView::Template::Error ( The asset "application.css" is not present in the asset pipeline. ) in Rails 7

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-7

After shifting from webpacker to importmaps in Rails 7. I keep getting this error no matter what I do to resolve it. Following is the output of the error.

```
I, [2022-12-02T11:33:16.828698 #2401]  INFO -- : [ca024b47-6054-444f-ab01-7f92d98e099f] Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2022-12-02 11:33:16 +0500
I, [2022-12-02T11:33:16.858168 #2401]  INFO -- : [ca024b47-6054-444f-ab01-7f92d98e099f] Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
I, [2022-12-02T11:33:17.079797 #2401]  INFO -- : [ca024b47-6054-444f-ab01-7f92d98e099f]   Rendered /Users/hamzaaamir/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/gems/devise-4.8.1/app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 10.1ms | Allocations: 3457)
I, [2022-12-02T11:33:17.080678 #2401]  INFO -- : [ca024b47-6054-444f-ab01-7f92d98e099f]   Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 11.0ms | Allocations: 4035)
I, [2022-12-02T11:33:17.080831 #2401]  INFO -- : [ca024b47-6054-444f-ab01-7f92d98e099f] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 223ms (ActiveRecord: 74.8ms | Allocations: 17972)
F, [2022-12-02T11:33:17.081562 #2401] FATAL -- : [ca024b47-6054-444f-ab01-7f92d98e099f]   
[ca024b47-6054-444f-ab01-7f92d98e099f] ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "application.css" is not present in the asset pipeline.
):
[ca024b47-6054-444f-ab01-7f92d98e099f]      6:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
[ca024b47-6054-444f-ab01-7f92d98e099f]      7:     <%= csp_meta_tag %>
[ca024b47-6054-444f-ab01-7f92d98e099f]      8: 
[ca024b47-6054-444f-ab01-7f92d98e099f]      9:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
[ca024b47-6054-444f-ab01-7f92d98e099f]     10:     <%= javascript_importmap_tags %>
[ca024b47-6054-444f-ab01-7f92d98e099f]     11:   </head>
[ca024b47-6054-444f-ab01-7f92d98e099f]     12: 
[ca024b47-6054-444f-ab01-7f92d98e099f]   
[ca024b47-6054-444f-ab01-7f92d98e099f] app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:9
```

I have run the importmaps rake task and added `sassc-rails` to compile my CSS files. It works fine in the development environment but produces errors in production. I have also run `rails assets:precompile`.

My code in **assets/config/manifest.js**

```
//= link_tree ../images
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
//= link_tree ../../javascript .js
//= link_tree ../../../vendor/javascript .js
```

My code in **assets/stylesheets/application.scss**

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import "./dashboard.scss";
@import "./sidebar.scss";
```

Comment: You could try changing the stylesheet name from `application.css` to `application.scss`, unless it is done already. And in .scss file, import the other files with the syntax `@import "your-subfolder/your-file";`.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code, post the actual code.

Comment: @JussiHirvi thanks for your help but I have tried this already.

Comment: @Chiperific its the output of the error, not the actual code.

Comment: You should post more context. For example, what does `assets/config/manifest.js` say? And the filename and contents of `assets/stylesheets/application*`.

Comment: It's still a picture and still annoying to read. Please post text, in a code block.

Comment: @JussiHirvi Thanks for your kind suggestions, I have updated my question with that.

Comment: You could try renaming `application.scss`to `application.css.scss`.

Comment: @JussiHirvi already tried that, didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

for **rails 7** run the following command

```
rails assets:precompile
```

this will create a assets folder in your public folder. Then restart the server.